# Нужна помощь с отправкой запроса на точку доступа сети WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, package, connection

Необходимо реализовать проверку точек доступа сети с помощью Android приложения для нахождения нужной. Алгоритм таков...

**1** Телефон сканирует возможные точки доступа

**2** Отправляет определённые пакеты на каждую точку

**3** затем проверяет, есть ли ответ от какой-либо точки (это будет реализовано на самом раздающем устройстве).

Вопрос такой... Как отправлять пакеты на точки доступа без подключения к ним по Wi-Fi. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хотя бы что гуглить, а то голова скоро взорвётся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко, то никак. Андроид не предоставляет такого АПИ. Но если очень нужно, то надо получить права root на устройстве и тогда можно работать с вайфай адаптером напрямую или установить программу вроде https://github.com/kriswebdev/android_aircrack

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Печально конечно, но буду тогда пытаться какие-то метки в SSID делать. Удачи!

Comment: в вайфай маячке есть много интересных мест для меток. возможно достаточно снять bssid (мак точки доступа) для трекинга. А ещё посмотри поля для hotspot2.0 и роуминга.